# add onTab for Items ListView.builder (for view image in new page cover) - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

To display the profile of each item, I need to display the same image (corresponding to the same ID) when the user clicks on each item on the next page (which is called PlayPage.dart here) in the section that is considered as the cover Main Page)
How should I add the clickable property to the ListView.builder widget?

I use info.json to get and display information

I have used two containers to display items (photos) in two columns
The right container displays the even indexes and the left container displays the odd indexes

info.json file & homepage.dart

```
[
  {
    "title": "one",
    "image": "assets/pexels1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "tow",
    "image": "assets/pexels2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "three",
    "image": "assets/pexels3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "four",
    "image": "assets/pexels4.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "five",
    "image": "assets/pexels3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "six",
    "image": "assets/pexels1.jpg"
  }
]



  List info = [];
  _initData(){
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/info.json").then((value){
      info = json.decode(value);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _initData();
  }
```

You can see the relevant images

[image]

This is the picture related to the program and its items
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use InkWell or GestureDetector with any widget you want

For example:

```
    InkWell(
                                                                                                      
        onTap:(){
                                                                                                        
        //any logic here
                                                                                                      
        },
                                                                                                      
        child: //any widget here,
),
```

Comment: I click on each item in each row
It returns only one for both

Comment: Thank you for getting a part related to the information about each item. Now, the best way to find these items (for example, only the image) is to get them on another page (I named it playpage.dart).

Answer (score 0):

You can use InkWell or GestureDetector like this

```
ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return `Row(
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: (){
                                  print("Response: ${info[i].title}");
                                },
                                child: Container(),
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: (){
                                  print("Response: ${info[i].title}");
                                },
                                child: Container(),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: I click on each item in each row
It returns only one for both

Comment: What do you exactly want? @mehrdadghadermarzi to click on image or the whole container?

Comment: @mehrdadghadermarzi I've updated my ans, please try that

Comment: Get details of each item that I can use on the next page

Comment: yes, you can send details to next page using argument

Comment: it was ok
I put a and b indices instead of i and the return value works fine

info[a]
Container1(...)
and
info[b]
Container2(...)

Comment: great, please accept ans if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for getting a part related to the information about each item. Now, the best way to find these items (for example, only the image) is to get them on another page (I named it playpage.dart).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a modal class to set types of your variables in it, then make you list of type  then fill it with your data.

One of the modal types would be a Function or Widget, through it you can pass `onTap()` paramiter.

After that you can make the list view builder simply with your list.

Comment: Thank you for getting a part related to the information about each item. Now, the best way to find these items (for example, only the image) is to get them on another page (I named it playpage.dart).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for getting a part related to the information about each item. Now, the best way to find these items (for example, only the image) is to get them on another page (I named it playpage.dart).

```
    class PlayPage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      PlayPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _PlayPageState createState() => _PlayPageState();
    }
    
    class _PlayPageState extends State<PlayPage> {
      List info = [];
  _initData(){
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).
    loadString("json/info.json").then((value){
      widget.info = json.decode(value);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _initData();
    setupPlaylist();
  }
      return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
       clipBehavior: Clip.none,
       children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image:

                     //get the image using info.json
                     AssetImage('assets/pexels1.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.cover)
          ),
        ),
```